# I am having problems with iron-ajax and iron-list trying to combine them into a feed element

Tags: polymer

I am trying to create an 'iron-feed' from iron-list and the iron-scroll-threshold demo :-

https://gist.github.com/AaronNGray/eb153af80037637e5ebf51d15c83ef19

The code is too long for Stack Overflow !

I have taken code from the 'iron-scroll-threshold.html' file and moved it into the iron-list component renaming it as iron-feed.

I am either having a databinding issue or some other issue I am not aware of.

Comment: Complete example :- https://github.com/AaronNGray/iron-feed/

Comment: There's a lot to digest so I probably missed something but it looks like you're using `iron-ajax` in the internal code and calling code (like in `test.html`). Could you use the auto binding template with `iron-ajax` and `iron-list` inside of `iron-feed`? That might make it easier to pull the data and render it. You should only have to use `iron-ajax` once either inside or outside the component.

Comment: Sorry the iron-ajax should only be in the iron-feed component. I must have hacked the code to try and get it working yesterday before posting it today. But it should be without that line

Comment: Removed the offending line in both the gist and in the repo

Comment: Hi, I cloned the repo quick and the demos seem to be working. What kind of error was it throwing? I noticed that the `href` property (line 440) should have a type of `'String'` but that doesn't seem to cause problems. The `webcomponents-lite.js` can be imported by index.html too.

Comment: Its the Scroll thresholds one that should be working, but via 'test.html'

Comment: http://localhost:8080/components/iron-feed/demo/test.html